# git one person workflow with local and live server only

Tags: git, drupal, vps

I have been growing a freelance web design business, mainly using Drupal. I now need to be more serious and start version control. When I run upgrades, I need to know if everything is still working properly.

I would like to use git. Here is my current situation: A VPS server with about 30 different websites.

So far, I have been building websites directly online using subdomains. That allows me to show the clients.

I have been studying Git workflows and am a bit confused as to what is the best first/next step for me...

First question: is a master repository on the remote/live server and a local repository on my machine a good enough setup? Most folks talk about a third server like github? If I could bypass that, it would be great!

Second question: if I understand correctly, I need a repository for each and every web project, right?

Third question: How do I go about starting? Which repository gets created first? Or do I just run git init inside one of the websites root folder?

Any help/advice would be appreciated! I can answer any questions you may have...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> master repository on the remote/live server and a local repository on my machine a good enough setup? Most folks talk about a third server like github?

3 repos is better... You should have one that is like the master repository thats essentially the remote origin for all others. Then you clone from that repo to your local machine and the subdomain or whatever. You make changes locally and then you push to that remote and then pull the changes on the subdomain. An alternative to this would be to simply deploy from the master repo tot he subdomain meaning that some deployment process would happen and that the subdomain code wouldnt be a git repo itself.

> I need a repository for each and every web project, right?

Yes, that would be best.

> How do I go about starting?

I usually create the remote "master repo" first, and then clone it.